# Closed irreducible subet in an open subspace

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. 
Let $C$ be a closed irreducible subset and $U$ an irreducible open subset.
I want to prove that $C \cap U$ is a closed irreducible subset in the 
subspace $U$. I was wondering if someone could show me the proof, because 
I came up with a proof, but I didn't use the fact that $U$ is irreducible
and I don't think my proof is correct. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the following characterization of irreducibility: a space $X$ is irreducible if no two non-empty open subsets of $X$ are disjoint, and a subset of a space $X$ is irreducible if it is an irreducible space in its subspace topology.

To show that $C\cap U$ is irreducible, then, we must show that if $V_0$ and $V_1$ are non-empty relatively open subsets of $C\cap U$, then $V_0\cap V_1\ne\varnothing$. Since $V_0$ and $V_1$ are relatively open in $C\cap U$, there are open $W_0$ and $W_1$ in $X$ such that $V_i=W_i\cap C\cap U$ for $i=0,1$. Let $G_i=W_i\cap U$ for $i=0,1$; $U$ is open in $X$, so $G_0$ and $G_1$ are open in $X$, and $V_i=G_i\cap C$ for $i=0,1$. Thus, $V_0$ and $V_1$ are non-empty, relatively open subsets of $C$, and since $C$ is irreducible, we must have $V_0\cap V_1\ne\varnothing$, as desired.

The fact that $U$ is open in $X$ is used to show that $V_0$ and $V_1$ are relatively open in $C$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess we don't need to assume that $U$ is irreducible then?

Comment: @user201886: You’re welcome. Yes, that’s right. For instance, let $Y$ be an infinite space with the cofinite topology, and add an isolated point $p$ to get $X$. Then take $U=X$ and $C=Y$: $U\cap C=C$ is irreducible, but $U$ is not.

Comment: I see. Thank you again!

Comment: @user201886: My pleasure!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Perhaps I'm missing something but this proof does not use that $C$ is closed, correct?

Comment: @mbert: I did not use that fact, but that’s because I showed only the harder part of what was wanted, namely, that $C\cap U$ is irreducible. The OP also wanted it to be closed in $U$, but that’s an immediate consequence of the fact that $C$ is closed in $X$, so I didn’t think that it was necessary to mention it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Of course, I was just making sure that if one removes all instances of "closed" in the statement then it still holds. Thanks!